# Codis - Redis cluster proxy installation

Tags: go, proxy, redis, twemproxy

I  am exploring a production-stable proxy for redis cluster called  [codis](https://github.com/CodisLabs/codis) . It is a mentioned as a great alternative to twemproxy, especially as one of my needs is pipelining and twemproxy does not offer that.

However the documentation in English is still a WIP and the replies to github issues are in mandarin.

I am trying to install this on

```
Linux version 3.13.0-74-generic (buildd@lcy01-07) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #118-Ubuntu SMP
```

I have installed go version 1.8 and I can see the folder `/usr/local/go/bin`. I have added this to the PATH variable as well.

However, when on executing the command `go get -u -d github.com/CodisLabs/codis`, I am getting the following :

```
package github.com/CodisLabs/codis: 
no buildable Go source files in /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/CodisLabs/codis
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the updated install outlined at https://github.com/CodisLabs/codis/issues/1180#issuecomment-286660086

seems the English docs might be out of date https://github.com/CodisLabs/codis/issues/1179#issuecomment-286662505

Comment: Thanks. I have been following the issue after raising it.